# Clojure, Flatten returns realized = 0

Tags: clojure

This is probably a common problem or I shouldn't be using flatten but I dont exactly understand whats happening?

The idea is to take a two-dimensions Vector `[[x][y][z]]` and return a single dimensional collection (dont really care what form for now e.g. `(x y z)` and `[x y z]` are both fine for now.

However if I do the following (`subbed` is the 2d vector:

```
(let [flat-coll (flatten subbed)                           
      header-less (subvec flat-coll 0 (count flat-coll))]
...
)
```

The value of `flat-col` is `realized = 0`, and I was expecting it to be the value of the flattened collection.

I guess its down to it being Lazy, is there a 'better' way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Isn't that what `flatten` is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flat-coll` is a seq since `flatten` returns a seq, therfor subvec does not work

how about `(take 3 (flatten [ [1] [2] [3] ]))` to get `header-less`

although I do not entierly understand what you are aiming to do, since you in any case get all elements.

maybe you want to do `(vec (flatten [ [1] [2] [3] ]))` to get a vector ?

Comment: It was the `vec` that was needed! Thank you, subvec was meant to start at index 1 not 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a vector as the result you can use transducers to flatten:

```
(into [] cat [[2] [3]])
;=> [2 3]
```

If you also want to get rid of the head:

```
(into [] (comp cat (drop 1)) [[2] [3] [8]])
;=> [3 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about vector or list can do also:

```
user=> (apply concat [[:x][:y][:z]])
(:x :y :z)
```

which returns a lazy seq.